# Jquery sum function causes a page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Why does putting this function in my script cause my page to reload, therefor losing all the values I am trying to sum?

```
  $('.price').blur(function () {
      var sum = 0;
      $('.price').each(function() {
         sum += Number($(this).val());
      });
      // here, you have your sum
  });​​​​​​​​​
```

I am using nodejs and expressjs if that has something to do with it. Thank you for anyone who took the time to read this.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Are you sure **this** code causes your page to refresh ? You should debug to see where it happens.

Comment: @Dom yeah, might take me a minute, but I'll give it a go

Comment: @dystroy yes. It does not cause the problem in the fiddle, but as soon as I insert it into my code. instant problems. Here is my fiddle anyway if the extra code can provide any extra insight. http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/qDCFM/2/ .

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint and debugging ? See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts

Comment: Are you sure you mean to attach your `blur` listener to `.price` elements during execution of the submit handler for `#addthisquote`? Or do you want to do that outside of the submit handler?

Comment: @dystroy yeah I just did. weirdest thing I've seen yet. ILLEGAL TOKEN AT LINE 22. Nothing was there, but upon trying to backspace the last semi colon the cursor was not moving, but blinking to indicate it was not frozen. After about 15 backspace presses it finally got to the semi colon. I put it back. Now all works. I know that must sound dumb, but a ctrl-z brought back the problem without adding any visible text. I am very confused. Thanks for the link and looking at the code, I would still be moving and deleting random page elements.

Comment: Looks like you had some illegal char in your code. Often happens when copying from jsfiddle. That's one of the many reasons I now use one of the many alternatives.

Comment: Good to know. I was still under the impression jsfiddle was awesome, I will check out my options.

Comment: Dont use `.ready()` in jQuery-Mobile, instead use jQuery-Mobile events http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: @Omar ok! did not know. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I believe it's a JQM `popup` problem. also I cant see elements with class `price` only input with id `price`, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on the code that prevents the

```
return false;
```

to be executed and so the form gets submitted causing a page refresh, I would recommend you to replace the submit handler to:

```
$('#addthisquote').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

That will always cancel the form submission and will give you the actual error on the console.